# Don't show "review suggested edits" if you already reviewed 20 edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, top-bar

I have hit 2,000 reps on Stack Overflow today (hooray!) and started reviewing suggested edits. After I reached the limit of 20 reviews, "review suggested edits" button is still showing in top bar, despite it is useless until tomorrow. Maybe to hide it when you hit the limit?

Comment: but 'grats on reaching 2k anyway!